# Cumbria Way in June. Do I need to make reservations?

Tags: uk, hiking, england, lake-district

Anyone here who has walked the [Cumbria Way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumbria_Way) in the lake district in June?

Is the weather moderate? Is it recommended to pre-book B&Bs or are there enough accommodation facilities along the trip?

Looking forward to some nice tips!

Comment: I've not done the Cumbrian Way before, so I don't know enough for a proper answer. As a general guide though, I'd say book your accommodation a bit in advance, as you don't want to get to the end of a day's walk and find you need to suddenly go another 4 miles to the next b&b! Weather might be stunning, might not, you won't know until a few days in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It being the Lake District in June, you can expect rain, gorgeous sunshine, fog, wind, calm, hot and cold, so for the first part of your question:

- take layers of clothing, with an outer waterproof / windproof layer
- take a hat
- take sun screen
- take midge repellent

That's the UK for you - very variable :-)

For the second part - I would suggest booking B&B's, especially if the 5 day forecast is good, as the route can get very busy very fast. There is a lot of accommodation along the route, but you don't want to be stuck.